# Is it possible to make any link smooth scrolling with fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Is it possible to make any link smooth scrolling when clicking on it with fullpage.js, I have tried the following however it doesn't seem to work. Is it is not possible should I use some other library for it or make my own.

```
$(".smooth").click(function (){
  console.log('button cliked');
  $.fn.fullpage.setScrollingSpeed(1300)
});
```

You can find fullpage.js [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

Comment: What do you mean ? Make links smooth? What link? Smooth to move where?

Comment: @Alvaro basically if I had a sections with the id of sectionone and i had anchor with href of #sectionone and a class of smooth it would scroll the user to the location rather than the jump you normally get.

Comment: fullPage.js does that for you. Just see [the example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage).